# How do I keep colors when piping "jq" output to "less"?

Tags: linux, unix, pipe, jq, less-unix

I have a simple json file and if I pipe the output of "jq" into "less", the colors get removed.

This works:

```sh
# yey, lots of colors
jq "." /tmp/myfile.json
```

This doesn't work:

```sh
# ugly output :( , no colors
jq "." /tmp/myfile.json | less -R
```

Any ideas on how to make "less" keep the colors?

Comment: Did you try `jq -C`?

Comment: Why would I, if I see colored output by default?

Comment: Because, as the answer added later below points out, jq does not by default add color output to a pipe.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It is `jq` that is suppressing the colours. From the `man` page

```
       o   --color-output / -C and --monochrome-output / -M:

           By default, jq outputs colored JSON if writing to a terminal.
You can force it to produce color even if writing to a pipe or a file
using -C, and disable color with -M
```

So, just use:

```
jq -C "." /tmp/myfile.json | less -R
```

and it will output colours regardless. The `less` command doesn't need the `-R` switch on my version, but I believe it does on older versions. If you see the `ESC...` codes, you will need that switch.

Comment: Thanks very much, exactly what's needed.

```jq -C "." /tmp/myfile.json | less -R```

Comment: That manpage first sentence is unclear, it would be more clear for the doc to say *"By default, jq outputs colored JSON only if writing to a terminal, not a pipe or file"*